# Submit Button Moves when I hover over it

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, plugins

Can anyone tell me why when I hover over the Submit button it jerks/moves to the right. I have looked through my php and css files and don't know where the problem is. I am using the WP Maintenance Mode plugin on Wordpress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/
My website: http://boasish.com

```
<div class="subscribe_wrapper" style="min-height: 100px;">
                <form class="subscribe_form buffer-inserted" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Get notified when it is ready via email"      name="email" class="email_input" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-email="true" aria-required="true">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
            </div>
```

I am aware of the `:hover` input on line 186 of the css

```
  .wrap form.subscribe_form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #444444;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0;

  }
```

I wanted the Submit button to change colors when I hovered over it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.wrap form.subscribe_form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #444444;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0;

}
```

This is the offending line, remove this from your css.

***border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0;***

Comment: Do we really need three of the _exact same answer_?

Comment: @3rror404 The need for repetition.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a left border on `:hover` which is causing the button to shift:

```
.wrap form.subscribe_form input[type="submit"]:hover {
    background: #444444;
    color: #fff;
    border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

Learning how to use your browser's developer tools makes this sort of debugging incredibly easy

Comment: I know, I wanted the Submit button to change colors when I hovered over it. Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: @k65 you've copied this CSS from somewhere haven't you?

Comment: If you just want to change the colour delete the border line

Answer (score -1):

```
.wrap form.subscribe_form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #444444;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

Line 186 :)

Answer (score -1):

in your style.css (line no:186 )

```
.wrap form.subscribe_form input[type="submit"]:hover {
background: #444444;
color: #fff;
border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0;
}
```

just remove the `border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0;` from css..it will be fine....